# how to send email through infusionsoft api?

Tags: php, email, infusionsoft

i want to send an email through infusionsoft api but email not shown i want to try but no email sent,here is my code:

```
 <?php
 echo "Hello World! <br/>";
 include_once('iSDK/src/isdk.php');
 //require_once"iSDK/src/isdk.php";
 $myApp = new iSDK();
 // Test Connnection
 if ($myApp->cfgCon("connectionName"))
 {
  echo "Connected...";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Not Connected...";
 }

  $myApp->sendEmail('conList','marif252@gmail.com','arif.liaqat@yahoo.com', 'ccAddresses', 'bccAddresses', 'contentType', 'subject', 'htmlBody', 'txtBody');

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe config your smtp server on php.ini

or you can install smtp server on your system

Answer (score 1):

//**Connect to the php SDK** https://github.com/infusionsoft/PHP-iSDK
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/src/isdk.php');
$app = new iSDK();


//**Set your connection, make sure you have the api key entered correctly**
$app->cfgCon("applicationName", "APIKEYGOESHERE");


//**Next you have to query Infusionsoft for the contact ids for your list of email address:**
$email = 'target.recipient@example.com';
$returnFields = array('Id');
$contact = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);


//**We need an array of the contact Ids to send email**
$clist = array_values($contact[0]);


//**Then you can send an email:**
$status = $app->sendEmail($clist,"sender@email.com","~Contact.Email~", "","","Multipart","The subject line of this email","The HTML content the body of this email.","The content of the plain text body of this email.");


//https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Email_Service#sendEmail